# Codeception WebDriver url remove trailing slash

Tags: webdriver, laravel-5.3, integration-testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to test Laravel 5.3 application. To bootstrap an application with testing config I have added index-testing.php entry point.

I have my codeception acceptance test config like this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://nginx/index-testing.php'
            host: 'selenium'
            browser: 'chrome'
        - \Helper\Acceptance_selenium
```

And here is a piece of output of the test scenario:

```
Scenario --
 I am on page "/"
  [GET] http://nginx/index-testing.php/
 I click ".apply-button"
```

So instead of http://nginx/index-testing.php it actually goes to http://nginx/index-testing.php/ which of course results in 404

How to I remove this trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

In a test I was getting home page like this:

```
$I->amOnPage('/');
```

When I changed to this:

```
$I->amOnPage('');
```

No more trailing slash present.